# Laravel 5.5 custom authentication issues

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to implement a third party authorization.

I send post request (using Guzzle) and get response as expected.

CustomAuthController.php

```
class CustomAuthController extends Controller {

public function auth(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->input('username');
    $password = $request->input('password');


    $client = new Client();
    $url = 'http://...................../login';

    $login_request = $client->post($url, [GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['login' => $username, 'password' => $password,], 'headers' => ["accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate"], 'decode_content' => false]);

    $response_status = $login_request->getStatusCode();
    $response_header = $login_request->getHeaders();
    $response_body = $login_request->getBody()->getContents();
    $response = json_decode($response_body);

    if($response_status == 200) {
        Auth::login($response->Login, true);
    }

}
}
```

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

But I get an error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given.
```

And I need help to solve it.

Comment: What is expected data of ```$response->Login``` ?

Comment: $response->Login returns username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Auth::login()` expecting Authenticatable model as first parameter, and your `$response->Login` is the username, you should check for the user first.

```
if($response_status == 200) {
    $user = User::whereUsername($response->Login)->firstOrFail();
    Auth::login($user, true);
}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors. But now I see blank page after login.

Comment: You can use ```return redirect('home');```

Comment: Now I think I don't need users table anymore. Is it possible to authorize without it?

Comment: @LinasMurauskas You can use ```Auth::loginUsingId($id)``` here, but you will need the id of the user rather than username.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your `$response` variable is string, which is not accepted as a parameter in `login()` method. Using `dd($reponse)` after you assign it, check your variable, and alter it to use the expected argument, which is an instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` .